# Multiple Spark applications with HiveContext

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark

Having two separate pyspark applications that instantiate a `HiveContext` in place of a `SQLContext` lets one of the two applications fail with the error:

> Exception: ("You must build Spark with Hive. Export 'SPARK_HIVE=true' and run build/sbt assembly", Py4JJavaError(u'An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.\n', JavaObject id=o34039))

The other application terminates successfully.

I am using Spark 1.6 from the Python API and want to make use of some `Dataframe` functions, that are only supported with a `HiveContext` (e.g. `collect_set`). I've had the same issue on 1.5.2 and earlier.

This is enough to reproduce:

```
import time
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

conf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sq = HiveContext(sc)

data_source = '/tmp/data.parquet'
df = sq.read.parquet(data_source)
time.sleep(60)
```

The `sleep` is just to keep the script running while I start the other process.

If I have two instances of this script running, the above error shows when reading the parquet-file. When I replace `HiveContext` with `SQLContext` everything's fine.

Does anyone know why that is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default Hive(Context) is using embedded Derby as a metastore. It is intended mostly for testing and supports only one active user. If you want to support multiple running applications you should configure a standalone metastore. At this moment Hive supports PostgreSQL, MySQL, Oracle and MySQL. Details of configuration depend on a backend and option (local / remote) but generally speaking you'll need:

- a running RDBMS server
- a metastore database created using [provided scripts](https://github.com/apache/hive/tree/master/metastore/scripts/upgrade)
- a proper Hive [configuration](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AdminManual+MetastoreAdmin)

Cloudera provides a comprehensive guide you may find useful: [Configuring the Hive Metastore](https://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_ig_hive_metastore_configure.html).

Theoretically it should be also possible to create separate Derby metastores with a proper configuration (see [Hive Admin Manual - Local/Embedded Metastore Database](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AdminManual+MetastoreAdmin#AdminManualMetastoreAdmin-Local/EmbeddedMetastoreDatabase%28Derby%29)) or to use [Derby in Server Mode](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveDerbyServerMode).

For development you can start applications in different working directories. [This will create separate `metastore_db` for each application](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables) and avoid the issue of multiple active users. Providing separate Hive configuration should work as well but is less useful in development:

> When not configured by the hive-site.xml, the context automatically creates metastore_db in the current directory