# Using windowing functions in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I am trying to use rowNumber in Spark data frames. My queries are working as expected in Spark shell. But when i write them out in eclipse and compile a jar, i am facing an error

```
 16/03/23 05:52:43 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception:org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Could not resolve window function 'row_number'. Note that, using window functions currently requires a HiveContext;
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Could not resolve window function 'row_number'. Note that, using window functions currently requires a HiveContext;
```

My queries

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{rowNumber, max, broadcast}
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val w = Window.partitionBy($"id").orderBy($"value".desc)

val dfTop = df.withColumn("rn", rowNumber.over(w)).where($"rn" <= 3).drop("rn")
```

I am not using HiveContext while running the queries in Spark shell. Not sure why it is returning an error when i run the same as a jar file. And also I am running the scripts on Spark 1.6.0 if that helps. Did anyone face similar issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have already answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36011943/3415409) before. The error message says all. With **spark < version 2.x**, you'll need a `HiveContext` in your application jar, no other way around.

You can read further about the difference between SQLContextand HiveContext [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666545/what-is-difference-between-apache-spark-sqlcontext-vs-hivecontext).

`SparkSQL` has a `SQLContext` and a `HiveContext`. `HiveContext` is a super set of the `SQLContext`. The Spark community suggest using the `HiveContext`. You can see that when you run spark-shell, which is your interactive driver application, it automatically creates a `SparkContext` defined as sc and a `HiveContext` defined as `sqlContext`. The `HiveContext` allows you to execute SQL queries as well as Hive commands.

You can try to check that inside of your `spark-shell` :

```
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.6.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.10.5 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_74)

scala> sqlContext.isInstanceOf[org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext]
res0: Boolean = true

scala> sqlContext.isInstanceOf[org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext]
res1: Boolean = true

scala> sqlContext.getClass.getName
res2: String = org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
```

By inheritance, `HiveContext` is actually an `SQLContext`, but it's not true the other way around. You can check the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/hive/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/HiveContext.scala#L80) if you are more intersted in knowing how does `HiveContext` inherits from `SQLContext`.

Since **spark 2.0**, you'll just need to create a `SparkSession` (as the single entry point) which removes the `HiveContext`/`SQLContext` confusion issue.

Answer (score 2):

For Spark 2.0, it is recommended to use `SparkSession` as the single entry point. It eliminates the `HiveContext`/`SqlContext` confusion issue.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
val session = SparkSession.builder
    .master("local")
    .appName("application name")
    .getOrCreate()
```

Check out this [databricks article](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/6122906529858466/431554386690884/4814681571895601/latest.html) for how to use it.

Comment: do you still need the Hive in your dependencies ?

Comment: `SparkSession` is contained in Spark 2.0. For the things I was using, Hive was not a necessary dependency. This might be different depending on what you plan to do, I cannot say for sure.