# Spark SQL: Percentile Calculation using Hive Generic Functions

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to calculate the percentile values of a column `x` using hive udf. However, when I execute the following using spark-submit, I get the following run time exception:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDAFPercentileApprox    
val x = df_grouped.select(callUDF("percentile_approx",col("x"),lit(0.05))).head.getDouble(0)
            println(x)
```

When I execute the above code, I get the following:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: undefined function percentile_approx;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.SimpleFunctionRegistry$$anonf
```

If there is a better way to calculate the percentile value, that would also be appreciated.

Comment: Can you check if your sqlcontext is an instance of hivecontext ?

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: Read this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36172311/3415409

Comment: I am using sqlContext which is not an instance of hiveContext.

Comment: You need to use a hivecontext in order to run hive specific functions. Check my answers about hivecontext [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3415409+%5Bapache-spark%5D+hivecontext) !

Comment: So did it solve your issue ?