# Initialising HiveContext in Spark CLI

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, command-line-interface, apache-spark-sql

When Initialising Spark in Command-line interface by default SparkContext is initialised as sc and SQLContext as sqlContext.

But I need HiveContext as I am using a function `collect_list` which is not supported by SparkContext, but is supported by HiveContext. Since HiveContext is a superclass of SparkContext ,it should have worked,but it isn't.

**HOW DO I INITIALISE HiveContext in Scala using Spark CLI**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In spark-shell, sqlContext is an instance of HiveContext by default. You can read about that in my previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36171349/using-windowing-functions-in-spark/36172311#36172311).

Nevertheless, `collect_list` isn't available in spark 1.5.2. It was introduced in spark 1.6 so it's normal that you can find it.

Reference : https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.6.2/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala#L213

Also you don't need to import `org.apache.spark.sql.functions._` in the shell. It's imported by default.

Answer (score 3):

You can do so by following the below steps:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc)
val depts = sqlContext.sql("select * from departments")`
```

Answer (score 1):

The sqlContext is a HiveContext

```
scala> sqlContext
res11: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext = org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext@4756c8f3
```

**[Edit]**

Import the functions before use it.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
```

Comment: `error: not found: value collect_list` this is what the console says after I use **collect_list** function

Comment: do you imported correctly? import org.apache.spark.functions._

Comment: `scala> import org.apache.spark.functions._
<console>:31: error: object functions is not a member of package org.apache.spark
       import org.apache.spark.functions._
                                             ^
`    **HOW DO I RECTIFY THIS** ?  Please help

Comment: @indian_authority which version of spark do you have ?

Comment: @elisah `      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.5.2
      /_/
`

Comment: sorry my mistake. it should be 
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._